# python-request with OpenSSL on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, ssl, python-requests, macos-sierra

Hi all
I met a problem when I tried to use python request package, you may find the error as follows:

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 512, in send
>   raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

Then I updated the openssl library to the latest version with brew in terminal.

```
>brew update
>brew install openssl
```

However while linking the latest openssl with

```
>brew link openssl -force
```

it came up error from macOS:

> Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
>   Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
>   deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
>   Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
>     -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

I'm not sure what to do in this case and there's barely no practical solution other than gaining root access which I just want to avoid.
Can anyone give me some hint? I really appreciate that.

BTW., my macOS version is Sierra 10.12.3.
I don't have ms dotnet installed on my mac. Please don't address that related answer.

Comment: Which url you are trying to access. If its your internal server that you yourself is managing then please check that ssl certificates on server are valid and build properly.

Comment: @xrage No I tried to access a public url on an external website. I do not think it is ssl certificates issue.

Comment: If you can share that url or similar url where you are getting that issue. Then it will be useful in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pyOpenSSL worked for me.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

If you are prompted with the following warning:

```
Cannot uninstall 'pyOpenSSL'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

You can do the ff:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL --ignore-installed pyOpenSSL
```